# Gnuplot plot every nth line a specific colour

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot, rgbcolor

I have a graph with several lines on it, read in from different columns in a data file.  I'd like each of the lines to be black, then every fifth line be red.  I've managed to get every fifth line be not-black but can't figure out how to specify red using the gnuplot rgbcolor variable syntax.[image: Here is my current attempt]

The line is use to specify these colours is:

```
plot for [i=2:max_col] 'data_file.txt' u 1:i:((i-1)%5==0?(255000000):0) w l lc rgbcolor variable lw 2.8
```

My question is, what do I place in the condition so that the line colour is red?  I'm using gnuplot 4.6 so the 255<<16 trick to get red produces an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use hex notation:

```
plot for [i=2:max_col] 'data_file.txt' u 1:i:((i-1)%5==0?0xff0000:0) w l lc rgbcolor variable
```

Or define two linetypes or styles between which you switch with `lc variable`:

```
set linetype 1 lc 'black'
set linetype 2 lc 'red'
plot for [i=2:max_col] 'data_file.txt' u 1:i:((i-1)%5==0? 2 : 1) w l lc variable
```